# How to I approximate $I = \int_{-1}^{1} \sqrt{1-x^2}\cos(x)dx$ s.t. the error is bounded?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, approximation

Edit: Because the original question was pretty trivial, I want to ask the same question but with:$I = \int_{-1}^{1} \sqrt{1-x^2}\cos(x)dx$.

How to I approximate $I = \int_{-1}^{1} \sqrt{1-x^2}\sin(x)dx$ s.t. the error is bounded? I know that the formula for approximation will be some sort of linear combination of $f(x_i)$ s.t. the $x_i$'s are roots of some orthogonal polynomial. The hint for this question was to not do Gram-Schmidt, so I'm guessing I need to use Legender polynomials, but isn't the error still going to include some derivative of $f$ and thus not be bounded. I'm sure I'm missing something. In the general case, how do I know whether I need to find a basis for orthogonal polynomials using a weight function or use Legender?

Comment: Hint: Use the symmetry of the integral.

Comment: I second @Michael, the value of this integral is $0$ by default. I posted as an answer, but deleted it because the value is known, but it doesn't help you in  your approximations

Comment: What if instead of sin(x) I had cos(x)?

Comment: Just for fun: The value of the integral with cosine is $\pi J_1(1)$, where $J_1$ denotes the Bessel function it usually does...

Comment: You might find a formula for $\int_{-1}^1 x^{2n}\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$, using integration by parts and recursion.  Then substitute it into the Taylor series for $\cos x$

Comment: You can use taylor series for cos and establish bounds based on the terms you decide to leave out

Comment: You can use Gauss-Chebyshev rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%E2%80%93Gauss_quadrature

Comment: Yes, thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1-x^2}\cos(x)dx=\int_{-1}^1(1-x^2)^{1/2}\cos(x)dx$$
we can say that:
$$(1-x^2)^{1/2}=\left(1\right)+\left(\frac12(-x^2)\right)+\left(\frac12\times\frac{-1}2(-x^2)^2\right)+\left(\frac12\times\frac{-1}2\times\frac{-3}2(-x^2)^3\right)...$$
$$=1+(-1)^12^{-1}x^2+(-1)^32^{-2}x^4+3(-1)^52^{-3}x^6...$$
and we know that:
$$\sin(x)=\Im\left[e^{jx}\right]$$
We also know that the formula is symmetrical so it becomes:
$$I=2\Im\left[\int_0^1\sum_{i=0}a_ix^{2i}e^{jx}\right]$$
where $a_ix^{2i}$ are the terms of that series